# Constructor calls after set_new_handler (std::new_handler func) failure, for memory allocation failures?

Tags: c++, out-of-memory

Whenever we use set_new_handler (std::new_handler  handle_mem_alloc) for handling memory allocation failures and if any memory allocation failure happens then handle_mem_alloc () will be called. If we are not throwing any exception from inside this function the new operator will not throw any error.

My question is, does constructor gets called in this scenario when there is mem allocation failure and we are not throwing any exception from handle_mem_alloc() function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/set_new_handler), the new handler must do one of these:

> 1. make more memory available
> 2. terminate the program (e.g. by calling std::terminate)
> 3. throw exception of type std::bad_alloc or derived from std::bad_alloc.

If the new handler returns, then the allocation is tried again, and if it still fails then the new handler (which is not cached, and might be changed by your new handler) is again called, and so on.

So the answer to your question is no, the constructor will never be called until the memory allocation actually succeeds.

Comment: The exception is any `nothrow` variant, which can fail silently by returning a null pointer. In that case, no object is constructed.

Comment: new_handler can also call `set_new_handler(nullptr);` which will make the allocation function throw `bad_alloc`.

Comment: Hi Yes Kerrek,
but consider a case when we will get any exception from the constructor. In that case the exception will be generated anyways... so nothrow type new operator will throw an exception and hence you should do safe coding for catching that exception so the whole point of using nothrow went for toss..please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim ... your reply completely answers my question. I also want your input on my reply to Kerrek. (Kindly comment for your agreement) Thanks again..